# Multiple Joins And Where Conditions All Together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been pulling my hairs for hours that finally I've come to SO to post this question. I read many questions, but it seems that nothing right is happening.

Table 1

```
a1
a2
a3 <-- linked with b3
a4
```

Table 2

```
b1
b2
b3  <-- linked with c3
```

Table 3

```
c1
c2
c3  <-- linked with d3
```

Table 4

```
d1
d2
d3 
d4
```

Columns to display with conditions:-

Column: a1 Condition: BETWEEN  '2013-9-13' AND  '2013-9-14'

Column: a2 Condition: a2 == '2'

Column: a3 Condition: only those results where d3's value is either 1, 2, 3 or 4

I've a PHP string like this "1,2,3,4". d3 should be selected if it is any of the coma separated value. Please also tell how can I use the PHP string for this purpose. In Oracle I used to use 'IN' operator like

```
'1' IN ('1','2','3')
```

and it used to solve the problem. But in Mysql I'm pretty confused.

Only those rows should be displayed where all conditions are met.

Thanks

(Note: The question requires a complete SQL query.)

Comment: there is operator `IN` in MySQL too... ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Thanks for that. And what's the solution of this complexity?

Comment: not sure about Oracle, but the following will bring one result: `SELECT 10 IN(15,10,25);` - result `1 row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.A3 = T2.B3
    INNER JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T2.B3 = T3.C3
    INNER JOIN Table4 AS T4 ON T3.C3 = T4.D3
WHERE
        T1.A1 BETWEEN '2013-09-13' AND '2013-09-14'
    AND T1.A2 = '2'
    AND T4.D3 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```